# Singularity in Poisson GLMM - when is it better to switch to GLM?

Tags: mixed-model, glmm, diagnostic, ecology, singular-matrix

I am analysing count data (count of observations per day of certain mammal species) at 12 different sites. My dataset consists of ~120 days of observations at each of the different sites. For each site, I have a total of 12 potential fixed effects (explanatory variables) which are essentially the structural and environmental characteristics of the sites monitored. 2 of the fixed effects are categorical and 10 are continuous.  I have scaled the continuous variables. The aim is to understand which of these characteristics affect use of a site by mammals.

I am using a Poisson distribution with `glmer()` from `lme4` package. I have included SiteID as a random effect `(1|SiteID)`, because of repeated measures - whilst the sites can be assumed to be independent, the observation count for each day at each site are not independent.

Example code:

```r
library(lme4)
m1 <- glmer(use ~ . + (1|SiteID), data=mydata, 
             family=poission(link="log"))
```

However when I run this model R shows me this message:

```r
optimizer (Nelder_Mead) convergence code: 0 (OK)
boundary (singular) fit: see help('isSingular')
```

**Note** I get the same singularity warning when using `(Date|Station)` as a random effect.

Based on Ben Bolker's guidance [here](https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html#singular-models-random-effect-variances-estimated-as-zero-or-correlations-estimated-as---1):

- I have 12 levels of the random effect so too few grouping levels is not the issue.
- I cannot simplify the random effect structure any more.
- My guess is that there is simply insufficient variation between sites...dropping the random effect from the model has no effect on any of the estimated quantities and is essentially the same as running a `glm()` model.

Question:

Should I
a) accept the singularity in the glmm and go on to use model selection to determine which fixed effects are important, or
b) proceed with a simpler glm without random effects, knowing that there are repeated measures (dates monitored) for each site and so the independence assumption is not met? Which is a statistically better approach?